# Why is this generator returning an empty list

Tags: python

I am creating a program that finds the roots of a polynomial. There is list (terms) of term objects. each term has attributes power, coefficient and sign(negative or positive). I would expect this generator to return the coefficient of the term with power 0 but it appears not to be working.
I know the issue is likely in the conditional as when I remove it, it returns a list of the coefficients for every term

```
[term.coeff for term in self.terms if term.power == 0]
```

```
class InvalidInput(Exception):
    pass

class Term(object):
    def __init__(self, term):
        self.sign = term[0]
        self.coeff = term[1]
        self.power = term[4]
        self.string = term

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.string

class Polynomial(object):
    #parse quotient string into list of its terms
    def __init__(self, quotient):
        self.quotient = quotient
        if len(self.quotient) % 5 != 0:
            raise InvalidInput

        self.terms = []
        self.term_count = int(len(self.quotient) // 5)
        for i_term in range(self.term_count):
            term = self.quotient[i_term*5:i_term*5+5]
            self.terms.append(Term(term))

        self.order = max( [term.power for term in self.terms] )

        print([term.power for term in self.terms])
        self.const = [term.coeff for term in self.terms if term.power == 0]

Poly = Polynomial("+5x^2-3x^1+5x^0")
```

Comment: This is not a generator, use parentheses instead of brackets

Comment: If the final list is empty that means either `self.terms` was empty or every single term had `power != 0`

Comment: Well obviously one of your assumptions isn't correct. Perhaps `self.terms` is empty, or perhaps it is never true that `term.power == 0`. Those are the two obvious explanations. Without a [mcve] we can't possibly help you more. Also, this is a list-comprehension, not a generator.

Comment: There is a term with power 0. Ill post some more of the code for better context.

Comment: @Numdoo no, there *obviously isn't* or else your list wouldn't be empty.

Comment: You are passing a *string* as the `term` paramter. A `str` object will never equal the `int` object `0`

Answer (score 0):

It works

```
from typing import NamedTuple

class Term(NamedTuple):
    coeff: int
    power: int

lst = [Term(4,0),Term(0,4)]

result = [term.coeff for term in lst if term.power == 0]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I realised my issue. I was comparing type string with type int which would always return false. I changed it so the attributes are stored as ints.